# In the declarative semantics of definite programs, $T_P \downarrow \omega$ is not equal to the greatest fixpoint of $T_P$

Tags: prolog, lattices

I am studying theoretical computer science using the book "Foundations of Logic Programming" by J. W. Loyd. I am in the part about declarative semantics of definite programs.

In the book, if $P$ is a definite program, we denote by $B_P$ the Herbrand base of $P$ and we define $T_P$ as:

> **Definition.** Let $P$ be a definite program. The mapping $T_P: 2^{B_P} \rightarrow 2^{B_P}$ is defined as follows. Let $I$ be a Herbrand interpretation. Then
> $$T_P(I) = \{A \in B_P \ | \ A \leftarrow A_1, \ldots, A_n \text{ is a ground instance of a clause in } P \text{ and }  \{A_1, \ldots, A_n \} \subseteq I \} $$

We denote by $gfp(T_P)$ the greatest fixpoint of $T_P$. I am currently trying to understand an example that shows that $T_P \downarrow \omega \neq gfp(T_P)$. The example is below:

> **Example** Consider the program $P$
>
> \begin{align*}
> p(f(x)) &\leftarrow p(x) \\
> q(a) &\leftarrow p(x) \\
> \end{align*}
> Then, $T_P \downarrow \omega = \{q(a)\}$, but $gfp(T_P) = \emptyset$. In fact $gfp(T_P) = T_P \downarrow (\omega + 1)$.

My doubt: why is $T_P \downarrow \omega = \{q(a)\}$?

I tried looking at the definition of $T \downarrow \omega$ (written below), but I think I am failing to make the connection between this definition in terms of complete lattices and the mapping $T_P$.

> **Definition** Let $L$ be a complete lattice and $T: L \rightarrow L$ be monotonic. Then we define:
>
> $T \downarrow 0 = \top$
>
> $T \downarrow \alpha = T(T\downarrow (\alpha - 1))$, if $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal
>
> $T \downarrow \alpha = glb\{ T \downarrow \beta \ : \beta < \alpha \}$, if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. Here $glb$ denotes the greatest lower bound.

Can anyone tell me how do we obtain $T_P \downarrow \omega = \{q(a)\}$? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our lattice is $L = 2^{B_P}$ with the partial order being set inclusion. In this case,
$\top = B_P$ and $\bot = \emptyset$. Notice that the Herbrand universe is
$U_P = \{f^n(a) \ | \ n \geq 0 \}$ and hence $B_P = \{ p(t)\ | \ t \in U_P \} \cup \{ q(t)\ | \ t \in U_P \} $.

If we apply the definitions we get:

> $T_P \downarrow 0 = \top = B_P$.
>
> $T_P \downarrow 1 = T_P(T_P \downarrow 0) = T_P(B_P) = \{ q(a) \} \cup \{ p(f(t)) \ | \ t \in U_P \}$, where we used the definition of $T_P$ in the last equality.
>
> $T_P \downarrow 2 = T_P(T_P \downarrow 1) = \{q(a)\} \cup \{p(f^2(t)) \ | \ t \in U_P \}$
>
> $\vdots$
>
> $T_P \downarrow n = \{q(a)\} \cup \{p(f^n(t)) \ | \ t \in U_P \}$

Hence, we have $T_P \downarrow \omega = glb \{ T_P \downarrow n \ | \ n < \omega \} $ and $T_P \downarrow n = \{q(a)\} \cup \{p(f^n(t)) \ | \ t \in U_P \} $, which let us conclude that $T_P \downarrow \omega = \{q(a)\}$ by the definition of greatest lower bound.